# Middleware to validade all form entries express js, node js

Tags: node.js, forms, validation, express, middleware

Is there some middleware function to validate all entries in forms for node js and express js?

I want to check for special characteres and i don't want to validade each form field at each time.

Thanks!

Comment: I think https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator will be good fit for your task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) could be a good fit. It is built upon [validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js), a popular validation library.

The *express-validator* is also [frequently updated](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/graphs/commit-activity).

**1. Set up and init**

```
expressValidator = require('express-validator');

app.use(expressValidator([options]));
```

[*see available options*](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#middleware-options)

**2. Configure the validation**

```
req.checkBody('postparam', 'Invalid postparam').notEmpty().isInt();
req.checkParams('urlparam', 'Invalid urlparam').isAlpha();
req.checkQuery('getparam', 'Invalid getparam').isInt();
```